# R: Find element in vector that satisfies two conditions

Tags: r, vector, conditional-statements

I have a vector of characters. Each element contains multiple values of the type `I|J|K|...`, where `I, J, K` may vary and be other characters, and the length is undefined.

I have two values, `current` and `next`, and I need to find the element of the vector for which the last value after the last pipe is equal to `next`, and the penultimate to `current`.

I have the following example working, but it is not elegant nor fast.

```
library(stringr)

myVector <- c("a|b|c", "f|o|o", "b|a|r", "f|c|v")
currentValue <- "c"
nextValue <- "v"

for(values in myVector) {
    #Split it
    split <- strsplit(values, split = "|", fixed = TRUE)[[1]]

    # If the penultimate is equal to current
    if(split[length(split)-1] == currentValue & 
       # And the last one is equal to next
       split[length(split)] == nextValue) {

        # DO SOMETHING
        print(values)

    }
}
```

The example return is correct: `[1] "f|c|v"`. It can be tested here: http://rextester.com/DVD4647

EDIT: There may be no match for the requirements (what would be the `else` of that `if`). In that case, a `NA` value would be fine as well.

**QUESTION**

Is there any way to write this with a one-liner? Or with something more simple?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use regular expressions with `grepl`:

```
pattern = paste0(currentValue, "\\|", nextValue, "$")
myVector[grepl(pattern, myVector)]
# [1] "f|c|v"
```

We build the pattern `"c\\|v$"` (using your variables for `c` and `v`). The `$` matches the end of the string, ensuring that the match is last and penultimate values. We need to escape the pipe `|` with two backslashes because otherwise it is the regex OR operator.

Note that if the values might include other special regex characters, `. \ | ( ) [ { ^ $ * + ?`, they will need to be escaped as well.

No splitting or for loop needed.